# Display columns into row SQL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

So I encountered a table where it has a design like so:

```
t_Schedule          t_Prof
----------          ----------
Date                ID  
ProfID              Name
ProfID1
```

What I want to achieve is something like:

```
Date         | Name
------------------------
June 1, 2016 | ProfName1
June 1, 2016 | ProfName2
```

When I use Join I get this result:

```
    Date         | ProfID   | ProfID1
    ------------------------------------
    June 1, 2016 | ProfName1| ProfName2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try following query:

```
SELECT s.[Date], x.Name
FROM dbo.t_Schedule s 
INNER/*LEFT OUTER when column ProfID allows NULLs*/ JOIN dbo.t_Prof p ON s.ProfID = p.ID
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.t_Prof p1 ON s.ProfID1 = p1.ID
CROSS APPLY (
     SELECT p.Name WHERE p.Name IS NOT NULL
     UNION ALL 
     SELECT p1.Name WHERE p1.Name IS NOT NULL
) x(Name)
```

Comment: thanks for this. I'm wondering if EXEC could also be done to fix my problem?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by using the UNPIVOT function. The answer is discussed in more detail below:

stackoverflow.com/questions/18026236/sql-server-columns-to-rows